# I want to get rid of the line length indicator in vs-code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Does anyone know how to get rid of this line in VSCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Preferences -> Settings then search for "Rulers"

you will see this option

Editor: Rulers
Render vertical rulers after a certain number of monospace characters. Use multiple values for multiple rulers. No rulers are drawn if array is empty.

press to "Edit in settings.json" at the settings file get sure the editor.rulers array is empty

```
"editor.rulers": [],
```